# How can I get data on laravel side from MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, laravel

On a Laravel 8 site working with MySQL 8, I create a procedure with 1 in and 2 out parameters:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getObjectsCount $$

CREATE DEFINER=`lardev`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getObjectsCount`( IN in_objectType varchar(100), OUT retCount bigint unsigned, OUT totalUsersCount bigint unsigned  )
BEGIN


IF in_objectType = 'users_without_active_tasks' THEN
    select count(*) into retCount from users where users.id not in (select distinct tasks.creator_id from tasks where tasks.status = 'T');
END IF;

IF in_objectType = 'users_without_completed_tasks' THEN
    select count(*) into retCount from users where users.id not in (select distinct tasks.creator_id from tasks where tasks.status = 'D');
END IF;

SELECT concat('retCount is ', retCount);
select count(*) into totalUsersCount from users;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and calling it :

```
call getObjectsCount('users_without_completed_tasks', @returnCount, @totalUsersCount);
select @returnCount, @totalUsersCount;
```

I got valid results.

But when I tried to run the same procedure from php page like :

```
$data = DB::select("call getObjectsCount('users_without_completed_tasks', @returnCount, @totalUsersCount)");
dd($data);
```

I got strange output :

```
+"concat('in_objectType is ', in_objectType)": "in_objectType is users_without_completed_tasks"
```

Looks like the method did not work on the server.

In which way can I get data on laravel side from mysql procedure ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2"
Mysql 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not return your output in the OUT parameters. Simply perform SELECT of these output values in the most last statement of the SP. Then on the client side use CALL like it is common SELECT, and receive the output. PS. If SP performs more SELECT statements then you'd receive not single rowset (like for common SELECT) but a collection of the output rowsets (like for multi-query with a lot of SELECT statements). And you must iterate over them.

Comment: The two `if` statements in the procedure can be written using `elseif` , as only one condition can be true at a time.  If the first condition check is true, there is no need to perform the second condition check.

Comment: @blabla_bingo I'd prefer single SELECT with CASE in WHERE.

Comment: i do curious with this, i never consider laravel query builder to support stored procedure to be used that way, but they seem to have [`selectResultSets`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#selecting-multiple-result-sets) on newer version.

Comment: @Akina , yes, we can use `where case when in_objectType = 'users_without_active_tasks' then tasks.status = 'T' when in_objectType = 'users_without_completed_tasks' then tasks.status = 'D' end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated once.

```
DB::select("call getObjectsCount('users_without_completed_tasks', @returnCount, @totalUsersCount)");

$data = DB::select('SELECT @returnCount as returnCount, @totalUsersCount as totalUsersCount');
dd($data);
```

Comment: I got error : ``` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select @returnCount as returnCount, @totalUsersCount as totalUsersCount' at line 1 ```

Comment: Try the updated once.

Comment: Thank you ! It looks like trick, but 2 DB::selects works ok. Please provide link where this is explained - never have seen such way...